# Just show me tree.png

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Someone can help me to find the problem of this code which only shows me three times the same image, tree.png ??

```
var bankImages = ["troyano", "backup", "tree"];

jQuery.each( bankImages, function( i, val ) {                
    $('#imagesContainer').css("background-image","url(../images/" + val + ".png)")
                         .animate({width: "show"})
                         .delay(500)
                         .animate({width: "hide"});
});
```

Comment: `.css()` doesn't wait for animations and other queued activity to complete, so the last image background will be set before it even begins to animate.

Comment: Oh! Perfect, thanks. But do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Yes, don't iterate immediately, but instead use the callback parameter of `.animate()` to progress to the next image.

Answer (score 1):

This is the worst way to do what I am thinking you are trying to do. 
You are seeing `tree` 3 times because `tree` is the **last item** in the array and is set as background for `$('#imagesContainer')`, regardless of any items in the array before it. (think of it as it all happens immediately, so of course the last item will be the thing you will see)

You need to come up with a different logic, perhaps consider using `setInterval` or `settimeout` technique to change between images.